# Python pygame calibrate joystick controller

Tags: python-2.7, pygame, user-input, joystick

I'm using pygame with a joystick controller. The joystick controller is not calibrated correctly, though. The right horizontal controller continually outputs bad values and does not zero correctly upon return to center position. Is this fully a hardware issue, or is there a method of calibration/continual calibration using pygame or another library?

Answer (score 1):

I had to calibrate my joystick by using software provided when I bought the joystick. I couldn't find a way to do so with pygame.

Are the outputs actually incorrect though? My outputs are never zero'd, but my program functions properly when using them.